# How to get an attribute value with lxml on html

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have some HTML that I want to parse with lxml using Python. There are a number of elements on the page that each represent a poster. I want to grab each poster's ID, so that I can then scrape a piece of information off the poster's page. Currently the poster's id is stored in the id attribute, so I want to use lxml to get the value of that attribute.

For example:

```
<div onclick="showDetail(9202)">               
    <div class="maincard narrower Poster" id="maincard_9202"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to grab the "maincard_9202" from the id attribute, so that I can then use regex to get the 9202. From there, I can use this value to get directly to the poster's page, since I know that the url redirect pattern goes from

https://nips.cc/Conferences/2017/Schedule?type=Poster (current page) to
https://nips.cc/Conferences/2017/Schedule?showEvent=9202 (poster page)

I was trying to use the following code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://nips.cc/Conferences/2017/Schedule?type=Poster')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
paper_numbers = tree.xpath('//div[@onclick]/id/')
```

but this returns an empty list.

How can I get the attribute value in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
paper_numbers = tree.xpath('//div[@onclick]/div/@id')
print(paper_numbers)
```

would give you

```
['maincard_9202']
```

It selects the `id` attributes of all `div`s inside a `div` with the `onclick` attribute...